# Could not initialize class Error when loading jcaptcha servlet

Tags: java, spring, azure, tomcat, servlets

Everything is running well when debugging my webapp at localhost, but when deploying it to to server (Microsoft Azure, OS:Ubuntu 14.04 tomcat7+apache ), the jcaptcha servlet cannot be found, and it throws Exception as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class "

```
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tjw.hrmanage.util.jcaptcha.CaptchaServiceSingleton
    com.tjw.hrmanage.util.jcaptcha.JcaptchaServlet.doGet(JcaptchaServlet.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the jdk version from openjdk7 to java-8-oracle and restart my tomcat, then everything is running well, thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Sure. Generally, recommend that using Oracle JDK instead of the others for development stage or work stage, such as OpenJDK or IBM J9.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app in ubuntu can not find the corresponding jar file. You can add this class's jar file to /lib and add reference for this jar in 'build path' in eclipse and then redeploy your project to azure again.

Comment: I have added the jar file "jcaptcha-1.0.jar" to the WEB-INF/lib dir of tomcat and add reference for this jar in MyEclipse but it's of no use after redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, there are three common reasons that will cause this error.

1. The class belongs to a missing JAR file or JAR was not added into classpath or sometimes jar's name has been changed.
2. The class is not in the path `CLASSPATH`, there is no sure shot way of knowing it but many a times you can just have a look to print `System.getProperty("java.classpath")` and it will print the classpath from there you can at least get an idea of your actual runtime classpath.
3. Just try to run with explicitly `-classpath` option with the classpath you think will work and if it's working then it's a sure short sign that someone is overriding java classpath.

Per my experience, I think your issue matches the first case. Please check your code and the referenced library.

Comment: I searched the similar question on the Internet and found that it may be caused by class BufferedImage. I try to add "-Djava.awt.headless=true" to my tomcat7 catalina.sh but same problem occured.

Comment: the code of JcaptchaServlet.java:40 as follow:
 BufferedImage challenge = CaptchaServiceSingleton.getInstance()
     .getImageChallengeForID(captchaId,
       request.getLocale());